# Docker on Ubuntu can't saturate CPU

Tags: docker

I have a simple Ruby app, basically it gets some data via HTTP endpoint, processes it a little, groups it and sends it in batches to some remote HTTP endpoint.

When I run this on bare-metal - I saturate 4 CPUs to 100% and get about `3000reqs/s` (according to `ab`; the app is a bit computationally intensive);

but when I run it in Docker I get only `1700reqs/s` - CPUs seem to peak at about 55-65%. The same app, the same settings.

[image: CPUs]

I tried increasing ab's concurrency. The app itself is hosted in Passenger, I tried running it in 20 processes, in 40 processes (Passenger runs the app). Inside Docker it doesn't seem to be wanting to go higher.

I run it via `docker-compose`, the host is `Ubuntu 14.04`

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108

$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
```

The load average is high in both cases (about 20), but it's not disc-bound.

```
$ vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- ---system---  ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in      cs  us sy id wa st
22  0      0 8630704  71160 257040    0    0    29     6  177    614   3  1 94  1  0
 7  0      0 8623252  71160 257084    0    0     0    16  9982 83401  46 12 43  0  0
43  0      0 8618844  71160 257088    0    0     0     0  9951 74056  52 10 38  0  0
17  0      0 8612796  71160 257088    0    0     0     0 10143 70098  52 14 34  0  0
17  0      0 8606756  71160 257092    0    0     0     0 11324 70113  48 15 37  0  0
31  0      0 8603748  71168 257104    0    0     0    32  9907 85295  44 12 41  3  0
21  0      0 8598708  71168 257104    0    0     0     0  9895 69090  52 11 36  0  0
22  0      0 8594316  71168 257108    0    0     0     0  9885 68336  53 12 35  0  0
31  0      0 8589564  71168 257124    0    0     0     0 10355 82218  44 13 43  0  0
```

It's also not network-bound. Even if I disable sending data to remote host and all communications are within the machine - I still see 55-65%.

The setup for docker and compose are default, nothing tweaked.

Why can't I saturate CPUs when it's running inside Docker?
Is there some hidden limit in Docker? 
How do I discover this limitation?

#### EDIT1 CPU set, CPU shares

`cpuset_cpus:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and/or `cpu_shares: 102400` (100 times the default) doesn't seem to change the situation.

There is also nothing interesting about limitations in `/var/log/*`

#### EDIT2 bridge/host network

It is also not the docker `bridge` network. The effect is the same when I use `net: host` in Docker Compose

#### EDIT3 Scale

If I run second container with same code with different port exposed - I can get the CPU load up to 77%, but still not 100% like on bare-metal. Note that each of those containers run 20-40 processes load-balanced with Passenger inside.

#### EDIT4 Ubuntu's problem?

Ok, it seems to have something to do with Ubuntu.
The same container ran on CoreOS - I'm able to saturate all cores.

[image: htop core os]

But I still don't understand the limitation.

#### EDIT5 DigitalOcean testing

To be completely fair I took 2 identical 16GB 8CPU instances on DigitalOcean, both in Frankfurt datacenter. 
I installed app on most recent Ubuntu and most recent CoreOS alpha.

```
CoreOS 949.0.0: Docker version 1.10.0, build e21da33
Ubuntu 14.04.3: Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108
```

I'm not sure how to get exactly the same builds - it seems that CoreOS has Docker builtin and read-only FS and with Ubuntu - I have no idea how to get build exactly e21da33. But the general version is the same `1.10.0`

I run `ab` from external machine on DigitalOcean also in Frankfurt datacenter to ensure that `ab` is not a variation. I hit the external IP in both cases. The parameters for `ab` are the same (`ab -n 40000 -c 1000 -k`), the code is the same.

The results:

```
 Ubuntu:   58-60% CPU    1162.22 [#/sec] (mean)
 CoreOS:     100% CPU    4440.45 [#/sec] (mean)
```

This starts to get really weird.
[image: htop comparison]

To give Ubuntu some chance I also tried adding:

```
  security_opt:
     - apparmor:unconfined
```

But that didn't change much.

#### EDIT6 Tested container under some other OSes:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3   NOT OK (50-60% CPU)
Ubuntu 15.10     NOT OK (50-60% CPU)
Debian 8.3       NOT OK (50-60% CPU)
CentOS 7.2.1511      OK   (100% CPU)
CoreOS 949.0.0       OK   (100% CPU)
```

Still have no idea what the limitation is. Seems to be Debian-related.

Comment: as you have 4 Cpus, I suppose you launch your docker container with `docker run --cpu 4` right?

Comment: I launch it with `docker-compose up -d` - I'm not sure what it does inside. I will try to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Seems there is no such option in `docker run`, only those: `--cpu-shares`, `--cpu-period`, `--cpu-quota`, `--cpuset-cpus`, `--cpuset-mems`

Comment: seems now `--cpuset-cpus=""              CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)` the syntax is `--cpuset-cpus=(0-3)` for you (or `--cpuset-cpus=(1-4)` )maybe

Comment: So, I tried `0,1` as docs specified - it did limit it to 2 of 8 CPU threads. Then I tried `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7` - it uses all 8 CPU threads, but again only 55-65% of them. :) Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: see also http://theza.ch/2014/09/17/cpu-resources-in-docker-mesos-and-marathon/ about docker, cpus and threads

Comment: I believe you actually want to start the container and specify the --cpu-shares flag. See this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources. it explains CPU usage for containers and removing the CPU quotas.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD As I mention in EDIT1 - I already tried it. Sadly, it doesn't affect situation.

Comment: same version of docker on core-os and ubuntu?  Are you hitting the container IP or the host IP and relying on docker daemon network forwarding?

Comment: Pretty much the same version, might be minor difference in build (a day or two), but generally 1.10.0. Tried both container (172.x.x.x) ip and host ip. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Docker is sensitive to kernel and limits. Did you try with the same kernel as cent os (Debian Jessie or Sid)?

Comment: Found a solution, I am facing this problem as well

Answer (score 8):

Please don't get excited (or flame me) - this is not *the* answer - I just need more space than a comment will allow!  I am not a linux or Docker expert but I really like this sort of problem and have done some research over the weekend and have a few avenues to explore that may help.  I don't have a test rig so have reached an impasse.

Theories so far "For Debian and Ubuntu...":

1. Docker is putting container and sub-processes into a cgroup that is
   being throttled in some way.
2. The scheduler for the OS and the    scheduler within the Docker
   container (systemd?) are in some way    'fighting' for the CPU and
   constantly displacing each other.
3. The OS scheduler is treating (a) the Docker Container and (b) the
   app inside    as separate competing resource requests and therefore
   giving each about 50%
4. It seems to me that the RedHat flavours of linux have in some way
   'integrated' docker (read "looked at what it does and tweaked their
   OS setup or Docker setup to be compatible").  What have they changed
   to do this? - it may be the thing that makes the difference.
5. There is a strong push for not using Docker under RHEL 6 but instead
   to use RHEL 7+  - What did they change in RH between these versions
   wrt. the CPU scheduling that makes them so keen on using 7+?

What I'd look at next:

- cgroup setup whilst running.
- Contents of any limits.conf files
- Differences in Docker config files between the version on RH and
  Ubuntu flavours.
- (If I had time) see if Docker on RHEL 6 had the problem (as RHEL 7
  doesn't)

Research:
https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/ 
http://www.janoszen.com/2013/02/06/limiting-linux-processes-cgroups-explained/ 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6791 
https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker/issues/15 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage 
http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf 
https://marketplace.automic.com/details/centos-official-docker-image 
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-docker-resource-metrics/ 
https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Fintelsdi-x%2Fsnap-plugin-collector-docker%2Fdocker 
https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos 
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8956 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/ 
http://www.unixarena.com/2013/12/how-to-increase-ulimit-values-in-redhat.html

If none of this helps I apologise!

Comment: Well, this is at least a good field for research :) Thanks, I'll try to look at it :)

Comment: Thank you for the reps.  I hope something in there does help.  I forgot to say that I like this sort of problem *except* when I have this sort of problem and a deadline!  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Starting Docker with **systemd** fixed that issue for me (Unbuntu 16.04). All of my 12 threads are used at 100% in a single container when benchmarking.

Stop Docker service:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

And start it with systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

To start Docker at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, started diving in and found this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt

You can specify `--cpu-quota` to Docker, and you want it to correspond to number of CPUs you wish to use.

For example, if you want the container to be able to use 4 CPUs you should set it to `400000`; if you want it unconstrained completely, specify `-1`.

Worked for us.

Comment: Even with --cpu-quota set to 1000000 on a 10 cores server, it stays capped at 400000.